# change mariadb column type from varchar to blob

Tags: sql, mariadb

How to change mariadb column type from varchar to blob or varchar2(500)

Comment: Add new column. Copy data. Remove old column. Varchar2, isn't that an Oracle type?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  There are a lot of `CHARACTER SET` issues that can easily be screwed up, so I need more info before telling you _which_ approach to take.  Do not experiment until you get a more definitive answer; you _may_ have destroyed data.

Answer (score 14):

You need an **alter table** query

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name column_definition
```

**Example:**

```
ALTER TABLE websites
MODIFY host_name varchar(50);
```

Comment: alter table db.table alter column user  blob;
gives me syntax error at blob

Comment: try modify not alter